# Add multiple input values and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add multiple input text values and assign it to a variable. i can add it now and send it to an id but i want to get it out as a variable. Please see below for the variable's condition after the js code

My HTML

```
 <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
 <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
 <input type="text" name="quant[3]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
 <input type="text" name="quant[4]" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
```

0

The JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".input-number").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".input-number").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

The above code adds up and sets the value to the id sum, i want the addition to not hapn when the first 2 values already gives an output of 5. the max value shd be 5 so the input fields should be like 2,1,1,1 or 2,3,0,0 or 5,0,0,0 summation value shd be 5 if it is achieved in the first input field itself then the summation should not continue.

Comment: what is the code that you have tried

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing platform that you can just order people to code for you.

Comment: dude i'm not ordering people here, just seeking out for a helping hand. @Derek朕會功夫

Comment: @satya i just dont know where to start dude. That's y posted a question here

Comment: @SubuHunter I am (and most people here are) willing to help you, but you really need to show what you have tried first.

Comment: @SubuHunter, just the starter: var y = parseInt(document.forms[0].quant[1].value) + parseInt(document.forms[0].quant[2].value);

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 i just updated the question

Comment: if the values are 1,3,0,0 and the i enter 2 in the 3rd textbox then the total will be 6. what should happen in this case?

Comment: i'm actually placing a plus and minus button next to the text box so it basically increased the number by 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this (push values to an array as an example or if you want string just concatenate the values):

```
var variable = [];
self.forEachValue = function(key, element){
    variable.push(element.value);
};
$(".input-number").map(self.forEachValue);
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: Thanks @tudor, But i want to add them